# Create a variable link with username in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, variables, hyperlink

I want to know how I can insert like this example link into a page in my WordPress:

```
<a href="http://example.com/uploads/2017/03/(username).jpg">Mars Month Info</a>
```

when every user clicks on this link, see his/her info about that month.
(username) will be a variable string that displays every user's username.

for example when "digi" user goes to that page, will see this link:

```
<a href="http://example.com/uploads/2017/03/digi.jpg">Mars Month Info</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current logged in user's username with the function

```
wp_get_current_user();
```

This returns a user object that you can get out the username value, among other attributes.

```
$current_user->user_login
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user